# What is this dot?

Tags: objects, bezier-curves, origin

I think this dot is the object's cursor. This is a cornice profile that I want to attach to a curve (path) and bevel. It appears the dot attaches to the curve path. Can this dot be moved to the corner of the cornice so it attaches properly. I don't understand this dot thing!

[image]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/27389/why-do-original-legs-have-orange-dots-but-mirrored-ones-do-not/27399#27399

Comment: it's the origin of your object, it has multiple purposes (for example change the rotation centre of your object). To move it to a point, for example a vertex, select the vertex in Edit mode, press shift S > Cursor to selected, then in Object mode press shift ctrl alt C > Origin to Cursor. But if you have no reason to move it, you don't have to.

Comment: Thank you, Duarte! I got it to work but definitely need to keep practicing it.